# Unwrapping curved surfaces to a tiled texture

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, bezier-curves

I have some curved surfaces that I need to unwrap to a tiled image. Here's what the curved surfaces look like, they are not quads:

[image]

Here's what the texture looks like:

[image]

Here's what I want the resulting surface to look like:

[image]

I've tried to do it myself with the "Align Auto" right-click option, but no matter how much I adjust it, it turns out weird:

[image]

I have some Curve objects which go along the path that the object needs to be unwrapped along, I wonder if there's some base functionality or some addon that could allow me to unwrap the object using the curve as a straight line guide?

[image]

I'm still fairly new to polygon-based 3d modeling and I don't really know what I'm doing when it comes to UV unwrapping.

[image]

EDIT: I have figured out a partial way to do it based on the advice from this video: https://youtu.be/6NMPrR82uhg
The way you do it is you create a reference mesh that you then UV unwrap the way you want, and then you use the Data Transfer modifier to "project" the UV onto the target object. However, when I use this method, this happens: [image: new method]
How do I stop that from happening?

Comment: Would you mind adding your blend file to your question?  I'd like to play with the topology to see if there's a better solution. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: The blend file I'm working with is huge, so give me a sec to copy out the relevant parts into a new file...

Comment: Ok, it's uploaded. It's just the objects and curves, nothing else.

Comment: thanks.  that was enough to prove my idea doesn't work.  sorry i couldn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/244317/35559) by @Chris, there's a way to wrangle a measure along the length of your original curves into an attribute of the mesh derived from them:

[image]

In this *XferMeasure* GN modifier of the kerb mesh..

- The curve is invited in, and turned into a mesh with a circular profile, which never appears; it's just used to transfer data.
- A vector attribute: `(Spline Length * Curve Parameter, 0, 0)`, is captured on the points of the resampled curve, and picked up by its mesh-version.
- Finally, the attribute is transferred from the 'Nearest Face Interpolated' to the kerb mesh.

[image]

- In the modifier's interface, that attribute is picked up as `measure`.
- `measure` is used as an attribute in a shader tree to generate stripes along the original curve length, in the mesh.

This is a vertex attribute.. the mesh has been subdivided and subjected to the *Face Menu > Tris to Quads* operator to improve the quality of the transfer.

[image]

This fails at the tips of your derived mesh pieces, in some places where the originating curves do not extend far enough. There's nothing to stop you extending the curves to cover that: the transfer will still work.

I'm pretty sure you could bake the stripes into an image map, if that's what you need.

I was trying to transfer the `measure` data to the actual coordinates of a UV map, as well? No luck yet.. if anybody knows how...? Feel free.

[image]

(Blender 3.0, Candidate Release)

Comment: I came up with a way of doing it by just making the transfer mesh long enough to cover the whole curve, but this is a much better solution. Thanks!

Comment: It wouldn't have worked when you made the original post (which I missed).. because this way needs Fields.. But it taught me some stuff getting round the plumbing :)