# How to make a GN attribute on a curve accessible by a shader?

Tags: geometry-nodes

The current Blender manual gives [this illustration](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/capture_attribute.html#examples) as a use-case for the *Capture Attribute* node:

[image]

Can anyone make this work? There is nowhere on the modified curve to store the output attribute, on points which don't exist before GN modification. If I create one with an arbitrary name in the 'Output Attributes', I can't seem to pick it up in a shader *Attribute* input node.

It would seem odd to publish an example in the manual which can't be reproduced.

Comment: .. not to mention, infuriating..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i just can guess and i assume they did it like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! So.. my problem was, the created mesh was not assigned a material at all. Not that the attribute wasn't being picked up. And you can give geometry an attribute just by naming it in the 'Output Attribute' field. And you can output the captured  _Curve Parameter_  directly, as well, which is what I really wanted. Great. (Nice choice of curve, too :D)

Comment: Man, you helped me that often ...i cannot count. I am very pleased and happy that i could help once! ;)